# Apache Proxy: No protocol handler was valid

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4, apache-modules, protocol-handler

I am trying to proxy a subdirectory to another server. My httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteRule .*subdir/ https://anotherserver/subdir/ [P]
```

The problem is that Apache is always logging this:

```
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /subdir/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule., referer: http://localhost/
```

So after searching the internet, I have activated these modules:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

(I know that I don't need all of them but I just activated them to be sure I am not missing one)

But this error still appears and clients get a HTTP 500.

How can I fix this?

Comment: seems it's need some HTTPS handler for the proxy request. Try HTTP instead...

Comment: I think you need `mod_ssl` and [`SSLProxyEngine`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine) with `ProxyPass`

Comment: @Deadooshka Yes, this is working. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup mod\_proxy on apache http server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475587/setup-mod-proxy-on-apache-http-server)

Comment: see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/401045/57019

Answer (score 605, accepted):

This can happen if you don't have `mod_proxy_http` enabled

`sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

For me to get my https based load balancer working, i had to enable the following:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Comment: I had to also had to do a 'sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel' , for my use case.

Comment: For me it was `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`. I also had to use [`SSLProxyEngine on`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine).

Comment: For me, xampp didn't start with proxy_balancer, but it is not needed, so I've removed it.

Comment: I also had to enable `mod_slotmem_shm`

Comment: For me on WAMP, I installed the modules above via the menu and had to uncomment `LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so` in httpd.conf

Comment: I needed `sudo a2enmod proxy_connect` , which is to tunnel https using CONNECT

Comment: proxy_http was the only additional module i needed to resolve this issue, on a ubuntu 16.04 install

Comment: Use loglevel warn proxy:trace6 or similar to get a more detailed message. `AH01144` is just a failure message at the end. Something has been declined, but you will only know this with a higher trace level.

Comment: in macos, i had to enable these components by commenting them out from `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file and then it worked.

Comment: How do i check whats wrong with my system? I am having this issue as well and I am using Ubuntu 18.04, apache2, php 7.2 with FPM.

Comment: Not sure, been too long - I'd look in your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file, and see if there's any signs. If none, I'd enable them one by one until it worked, then disable some until it didnt work

Answer (score 27):

For my Apache2.4 + php5-fpm installation to start working, I needed to activate the following Apache modules:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
```

No need for `proxy_http`, and this is what sends all `.php` files straight to php5-fpm:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Yes, for fcgi this is true, but I had a HTTP proxy. :)

Answer (score 22):

In my case, I needed `proxy_ajp` module.

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_ajp
```

Comment: Thank you! It was `proxy_ajp` that I needed!

Answer (score 15):

This was happening for me in my Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) setup. In my case, the error I was seeing was:

```
... AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /~socket.io/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

The configuration related to this was:

```
  ProxyPass /~socket.io/ ws://127.0.0.1:8090/~socket.io/
  ProxyPassReverse /~socket.io/ ws://127.0.0.1:8090/~socket.io/
```

"`No protocol handler was valid for the URL /~socket.io/`" meant that Apache could not handle the request being sent to "`ws://127.0.0.1:8090/~socket.io/`"

I had `proxy_http` loaded, but also needed `proxy_wstunnel`. Once that was enabled all was good.

Comment: indeed `proxy_wstunnel` was needed for me also

Comment: proxy_wstunnel is obviously required for websockets (in addition to proxy_http)

Answer (score 10):

To clarify for future reference, a2enmod, as is suggested in several answers above, is for Debian/Ubuntu. Red Hat does not use this to enable Apache modules - instead it uses LoadModule statements in httpd.conf.

More here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/56394/how-do-i-enable-apache-modules-from-the-command-line-in-redhat

The resolution/correct answer is in the comments on the OP:

*I think you need mod_ssl and SSLProxyEngine with ProxyPass – Deadooshka May 29 '14 at 11:35*

*@Deadooshka Yes, this is working. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it – das_j May 29 '14 at 12:04*

Answer (score 4):

I am posting an answer here, since I had the same error message for a different reason.

This error message can happen, for example, if you are using apache httpd to proxy requests from a source on protocol A to target on protocol B.

Here is the example of my situation:

> AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /sockjs-node/info
>   (scheme 'ws').

In the case above, what was happening was simply the following.
I had enabled mod proxy to proxy websocket requests to nodejs based on path /sockjs-node.

The problem is that node does not use the path /sockjs-node for websocket requests exclusively. It also uses this path for hosting REST entrypoints that deliver information about websockets.

In this manner, when the application would try to open http://localhost:7001/sockjs-node/info, apache httpd would be trying to route the rest call from HTTP protocol to to a Webscoket endpoint call. Node did not accept this.

This lead to the exception above.

So be mindful that even if you enable the right modules, if you try to do the wrong forwarding, this will end with apache httpd informing you that the protocol you tried to use on the target server is not valid.

Comment: It was probably proxy_wstunnel. See first comment on accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, all modules were correctly set up (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension is a good starter) & **I had the redirection working for a base url**, let's say `/mysite/`
but I got the errors for any child ULR, let's say `/mysite/login/`

`http://reverse-proxy.dns.com/mysite/` was properly redirected to the remote servers while `http://reverse-proxy.dns.com/mysite/login/` failed at the Apache2 reverse proxying with OP's error message.

The issue was the ending `/` character in the proxypass directive "/mysite/". Working configuration for child URL is :

```
<Proxy balancer://mysite_cluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.x.x.10:8080/mysite
    BalancerMember http://192.x.x.11:8080/mysite
</Proxy>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [...]
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/mysite" "balancer://mysite_cluster"
    ProxyPassReverse "/mysite" "balancer://mysite_cluster"       
</VirtualHost>
```

Trailing `/` truly are tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get an `uwsgi://` working, but somehow the manual thought it was clear to me that I actually needed `mod_proxy_uwsgi`. It was not. Here is how you do it: [How to compile mod_proxy_uwsgi or mod_uwsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17415311/1025430)

Answer (score 1):

For me all above-mentioned answers was enabled on xampp still not working. Enabling below module made virtual host work again

```
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
```