# Redirect url to specific port not working in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, websocket

I am working on 2 servers and .htaccess file working on 1 server but not working on second server.

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^socket.io/(.*)$ ws://example.com:3000/socket.io/?$1  [P,QSA,L]
```

I am working on socket, so i dont want to show :port in url, so i just redirect url to port within htaccess

**Url examples server 1,**

```
ws://example.com/socket.io/etc Redirect ON ws://example.com:3000/socket.io/etc (working)

http://example.com/socket.io/etc Redirect ON ws://example.com:3000/socket.io/etc (working)
```

But on server 2, same code on different domain return "Internal Server Error"

> I dont want to change my code, because it is my backup server, so i
>   want to run same code, but what i am missing? Is there any apache extension
>   required or what i am missing?

Comment: If you get "Internal server error", there should be an entry in apache error log with more info

Comment: Error in Apache log: AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /socket.io/ (scheme 'ws'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Comment: Looks like you need to [enable mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526281/websockets-and-apache-proxy-how-to-configure-mod-proxy-wstunnel#27534443)

Comment: Problem solved, Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53523424/11959017
Thanks